# Why is my PC hanging when I insert a DVD?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, dvd

I have a computer with a 500GB hard drive, an 80GB hard drive, and a CD/DVD drive running on a 450W Power Supply.

When I connect the power supply to all the devices at the same time and insert a DVD, the PC freezes. But When I remove the DVD the PC is back to normal. Is the power supply limited to the number of devices? Because by Using any two devices and not connecting a third one, the PC works fine.

- Processor : AMD Phenom-x2 555 Black Edition
- OS : Windows 7 (64 Bit)
- Both Hard Disk have Sata cables

Softwares Installed :

[image: pic]

Does a CD/DVD have additional drivers or it will be provided by OS by default?

Comment: This won't have anything to do with the power supply. It's more likely to be a software issue (Or perhaps a bad DVD drive). Could you [edit] your question and include more details about the OS and other related software you're using? If you're using IDE/PATA, then it could also be an improperly configured Master/Slave setup.

Comment: I have edited my post, anything else u need?

Comment: Actually, it’s not unreasonable for it to be the power-supply. If the system works fine right up until the DVD drive spins up (and thus draws more power), then it seems perfectly reasonable to consider the PSU as the issue. That said, unless the PSU is cheap or low-quality, it *should* be able to handle a couple of HDDs and a DVD drive. When you say “freeze”, what exactly do you mean? Can you fix it by just ejecting the disc? Do you have to reboot? Do you have to press the Reset button? Can you reproduce the problem by pressing `Pause` at the BIOS or Windows boot screens and putting a disc in?

Comment: On Ejecting disc, Windows is back to normal. Dont have to reboot. Does DVD reading consume more power than reading CD? & Yes, I have cheap/low quality PSU, thats for sure. I am buying graphic card ATI RADEON HD 6450, do I need more watt power supply? or should I buy 450 watt & If not how much watt PS should I buy?

Comment: Get a volt meter if your motherboard does not have voltage monitoring software.  Connect all devices, one pair should be 4.75v to 5.25v and the second 11.4v to 12.6v. Also a dirty CD/DVD will cause your system to freeze, if it is dirty enough. Most of the time the dirt particles are too small to see and therefore you just need to clean it. If you clean and test say 10 different CDs, and if possible a brand new one, and all of them freeze the system then I would look at the power supply and other components